# Dynamically change UI color according to image in android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am building a music player in xamarin android, now i want to change the UI color of music player  automatically according to mp3 thumbnail.

We want to change the purple layout color present at the bottom to the one present in the thumbnail i.e. orange color

[image: We want to change the purple layout color present at the bottom to the one present in the thumbnail i.e. orange color]

Can anyone please help..

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here? Do you want to set the color of the action bar according to the number of pixels which use that color, or according to the mean (average) of the colors, ect. ?

Comment: Yes average of the color.

Answer (score 0):

1)First you need to fetch color of that thumbnail image.

```
    // Create a Bitmap object from an image file.
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Grapes.jpg");

// Get the color of a pixel within myBitmap.
Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
```

2) so now you have your color you can simply set it to your view.
by using
        view.SetBackgroundColor(pixelColor);
where view is your layout or button or any other view.

hope this helps..